# Apply class to html element in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div class="weather-app-wrapper" *ngIf="weather !== undefined">
    <div class="weather-wrapper" *ngFor="let forecast of weather.forecastDays">
        <div class="weather-card">
            <div class="forecast-icon" [ngClass]="{{forecast.condition}}"></div>
            <h1>{{forecast.tempMin}}º - {{forecast.tempMax}}º</h1>
            <p>{{forecast.day}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to apply a class to an html element in this line: `<div class="forecast-icon" [ngClass]="{{forecast.condition}}"></div>` although it's giving an error. Is there a way to do this in html or does it have to be done in typescript? I know how to do it for static html, but not in a loop creating html elements. I know `forecast.condition` holds a valid string, and the loop is looped 5 times, the rest of the properties work just fine. What's a way I can do this?

Example:

```
//forecast.condition = "sunny"
    <div class="forecast-icon"> 
should turn into 
    <div class="forecast-icon sunny"> 
on the html page
```

Here's the forecast model:

```
export class ForecastDay {
    tempMin: number;
    tempMax: number;
    day: string;
    condition: string;
}
```

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in [{{forecast.condition}}] in ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 (" weather.forecastDays">
        <div class="weather-card">
            <div class="forecast-icon" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{{forecast.condition}}"></div>
            <h1>{{forecast.tempMin}}º - {{forecast.tempMax"): ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 2 in [{{forecast.condition}}] in ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 (" weather.forecastDays">
        <div class="weather-card">
            <div class="forecast-icon" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{{forecast.condition}}"></div>
            <h1>{{forecast.tempMin}}º - {{forecast.tempMax"): ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 21 in [{{forecast.condition}}] in ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 (" weather.forecastDays">
        <div class="weather-card">
            <div class="forecast-icon" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{{forecast.condition}}"></div>
            <h1>{{forecast.tempMin}}º - {{forecast.tempMax"): ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 Parser Error: Unexpected token } at column 21 in [{{forecast.condition}}] in ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 (" weather.forecastDays">
        <div class="weather-card">
            <div class="forecast-icon" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{{forecast.condition}}"></div>
            <h1>{{forecast.tempMin}}º - {{forecast.tempMax"): ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 Parser Error: Unexpected token '}' at column 22 in [{{forecast.condition}}] in ng:///AppModule/WeatherComponent.html@3:39 (" weather.forecastDays">
        <div class="weather-card">
            <div class="forecast-icon" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{{forecast.condition}}"></div>
```

Comment: `[ngClass]="{ 'yourclass': forecast.condition }"` should be like this..

Comment: Does `forecast.condition` contain the name of the class that you want to add?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes I updated with an example

Comment: @Sanoj_V I did `[ngClass]="{ 'forecast-icon': forecast.condition }"` but it doesn't apply the class, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use interpolation with `[ngClass]`. You can set the class with:

```
<div class="forecast-icon" [ngClass]="forecast.condition"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!